# How to get the latest date for a specific day of the week in Bash

Tags: bash, date

**Q:** How can the latest date for a `given_day_of_the_week`?

**Example:** For example if today is the *2016-04-21*, I just want to get the date for a `given_day_of_the_week` for example `Monday` which would be the `2016-04-18`. This date will be still returned if the code was run tomorrow, up until the day before the following `given_day_of_the_week`.

**Explanation:** The code should return the latest `given_day_of_the_week`'s (`Monday`) date until the Sunday 2016-04-24, then the same bit of code running will return the `2016-04-25` next week.

Comment: Bash does not include date manipulation functions. You can probably do what you want by using your system's `date` command, but usage of that command varied by operating system, and you haven't mentioned what OS you're using.  Also ... what have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Requires GNU date:

```
today_dow=$(date +%w)
days=(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday)
for ((dow=0; dow<7; dow++)); do 
    if ((dow < today_dow)); then 
        date -d "last ${days[dow]}"
    else 
        date -d "${days[dow]}"
    fi
done
```

```
Sun Apr 17 00:00:00 EDT 2016
Mon Apr 18 00:00:00 EDT 2016
Tue Apr 19 00:00:00 EDT 2016
Wed Apr 20 00:00:00 EDT 2016
Thu Apr 21 00:00:00 EDT 2016
Fri Apr 22 00:00:00 EDT 2016
Sat Apr 23 00:00:00 EDT 2016
```

So we can do:

```
given_day_of_the_week() {
    local days=(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday)
    local today_dow=$(date +%w)
    local dow datestr
    for ((dow=0; dow<7; dow++)); do 
        if [[ "${days[dow],,}" == "${1,,}" ]]; then
            if ((dow < today_dow)); then 
                datestr="last ${days[dow]}"
            else
                datestr="${days[dow]}"
            fi
            date -d "$datestr" "+%F"
        fi
    done
}
```

Resulting in:

```
$ given_day_of_the_week tuesday
2016-04-19
$ given_day_of_the_week friday
2016-04-22
```

Hardcoding the weekday names like that will give you problems if you're in a different locale

---

Responding to @ryenus's comment:

```
$ given_day_of_the_week() { 
    local -A days=([sunday]=0 [monday]=1 [tuesday]=2 [wednesday]=3 [thursday]=4 [friday]=5 [saturday]=6)
    local today_dow=$(date +%w)
    local datestr=${1,,}
    local dow=${days[$datestr]}
    [[ -z "$dow" ]] && { echo "error: unknown day: '$1'" >&2; return 1; }
    (( dow < today_dow )) && datestr="last $datestr"
    date -d "$datestr" "+%F"
}
$ given_day_of_the_week friday
2016-04-22
$ given_day_of_the_week monday
2016-04-18
$ given_day_of_the_week FOO
error: unknown day: 'FOO'
```

Comment: Upvoted! for your smart use of `date -d` and `date -d last ...`.

Comment: And you might consider to directly compare day_of_week, without looping, to decide whether to add the prefix last: `[ $(date -d monday +%w) -lt $(date +%w) ] && date_str_prefix="last "`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @glenn-jackman's answer, but simpler:

```
given_day_of_the_week=$1
f='%A %Y-%m-%d'
tomorrow=`date -d 'tomorrow' +"$f"`
today=`date -d 'today' +"$f"`
last5=`seq 1 5 | xargs -I{} date -d '{} day ago' +"$f"`
echo -e "$tomorrow\n$today\n$last5" |
    grep -i $given_day_of_the_week |
    cut -d' ' -f2
```

Note: this answer does give tomorrow's date for Monday if used on a Sunday. It also gives tomorrow's date for Tuesday if used on a Monday. Not 100% sure if that's what you had in mind.

If instead the idea is to always go with the current Sunday - Saturday, this will do it:

```
given_day_of_the_week=$1
f='%A %Y-%m-%d'

[ `date +%A` = 'Sunday' ] && first=`date -d 'today' +"$f"` ||
    first=`date -d 'last Sunday' +"$f"`

rest=`seq 1 6 | xargs -I{} date -d "$first +{} day" +"$f"`

echo -e "$first\n$rest" |
    grep -i $given_day_of_the_week |
    cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# requires bash 4.x and GNU date
last_kday() {
  local kday=$1
  local -A numbers=([sunday]=0   [monday]=1 [tuesday]=2 [wednesday]=3
                    [thursday]=4 [friday]=5 [saturday]=6)
  if [[ $kday == *day ]]; then
    kday=${numbers[${kday,,}]}
  elif [[ $kday != [0-6] ]]; then
    echo >&2 "Usage: last_kday weekday"
    return 1
  fi

  local today=$(date +%w)
  local days_ago=$(( today - kday ))
  if (( days_ago < 0 )); then let days_ago+=7; fi
  date -d "$days_ago days ago" +%F
}
```